# is their a way to implementing sweetalert2 as i want

Tags: javascript, php, html, sweetalert2

i am trying to add sweetalert2 to my bootstrap theme.
the process is simple when submit button is clicked check for validity
if valid then procced to show sweet alert in loading mood until data is entered into database. when data is in database show success if something went wrong show error message

this is the code i have now

```
    <!DOCTYPE html\>
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="src/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="layouts/horizontal-dark-menu/css/light/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="layouts/horizontal-dark-menu/css/dark/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/assets/css/light/elements/alert.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/assets/css/dark/elements/alert.css">   
    <link href="src/assets/css/light/scrollspyNav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="src/assets/css/dark/scrollspyNav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/plugins/src/sweetalerts2/sweetalerts2.css">
    <link href="src/plugins/css/light/sweetalerts2/custom-sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="src/assets/css/dark/scrollspyNav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="src/plugins/css/dark/sweetalerts2/custom-sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="src/assets/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="src/assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

$("#email").inputmask(
{
mask:"*{1,20}\[.*{1,20}\]\[.*{1,20}\]\[.*{1,20}\]@*{1,20}\[.*{2,6}\]\[.*{1,2}\]",
greedy:!1,onBeforePaste:function(m,a){return(m=m.toLowerCase()).replace("mailto:","")},
definitions:{"*":
{
validator:"\[0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'\*+/=?^\_\`{|}\~-\]",
cardinality:1,
casing:"lower"
}
}
}
);

    </script>
    
    
        Supplier Name
        
        
            Looks Good!
        
        
            InValid Supplier Name.
        
        Supplier Address 
        
        
        
        Supplier E-Mail
        
        
            Looks Good!
        
        Supplier Phone #
        
        
            Looks Good!
        
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary mixin" id="btnSubmit"\>Submit form</button>
    
    <script src="src/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/src/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/src/mousetrap/mousetrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/src/waves/waves.min.js"></script>
    <script src="layouts/horizontal-dark-menu/app.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/src/highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="src/assets/js/scrollspyNav.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/src/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/src/input-mask/input-mask.js"></script>
    <script src="src/assets/js/forms/bootstrap_validation/bs_validation_script.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/src/sweetalerts2/sweetalerts2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/plugins/src/sweetalerts2/custom-sweetalert.js"></script>
    
    
    // Phone Number2
    $("#ph-number2").inputmask({mask:"(999) 9999-9999"});

document.querySelector('.widget-content .mixin').addEventListener('click', function() {
const Toast = Swal.mixin({
toast: true,
position: 'top-end',
showConfirmButton: false,
timer: 3000,
timerProgressBar: true,
didOpen: (toast) =\> {
toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
}
})

    Toast.fire({
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Saved successfully'
    })

})
```

Comment: That could work if you use an ajax request to submit the form. That way, the request to the server runs in the background and doesn't refresh your whole page

Comment: yes but also it will stop the page from validating data input using javascript before it sends the form data

Comment: Why would it? You can still validate if you want. It's your code, you can do that if you need to.

Comment: yes i know and u explained my issue perfectly if i can keep the sweetalert loading and then try inserting the data (if inserted) will then stop the loading and show success message and reloading a fresh page afterwards to insert new data  (if error occured) show failed message and return to same page without refreshing it

Comment: Yep, you can use AJAX for all that

Answer (score -1):

To display a Bootstrap SweetAlert success message after inserting data into a database, you'll need to combine server-side code (e.g., PHP) with JavaScript. Here's an example workflow:

Set up your database connection and insert the data using server-side code (e.g., PHP). Ensure that the insertion process is successful and returns a response indicating success or failure.

In your server-side code, after a successful database insertion, you can set a flag or return a specific response (e.g., JSON) to indicate success.

In your JavaScript code, handle the response from the server. If the response indicates success, use SweetAlert to display the success message using the Bootstrap styling.

**Here's an example using jQuery and PHP:**

> Perform the database insertion and check if it was successful  Assume
> $successFlag is set to true if insertion is successful, otherwise
> false

```
<?php
    if ($successFlag) {
        $response = array('success' => true);
    } else {
        $response = array('success' => false);
    }
    
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

> JavaScript code using jQuery and SweetAlert

```
$.ajax({
url: 'insert_data.php',
type: 'POST',
data: formData, // Include your data to be inserted here
dataType: 'json',
success: function(response) {
    if (response.success) {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Success!',
            text: 'Data inserted successfully',
            icon: 'success',
            confirmButtonText: 'OK'
        });
    } else {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Error!',
            text: 'Failed to insert data',
            icon: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'OK'
        });
    }
},
error: function() {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Error!',
        text: 'An error occurred',
        icon: 'error',
        confirmButtonText: 'OK'
    });
    }
});
```

In this example, the server-side PHP code handles the database insertion and returns a JSON response indicating success or failure. The JavaScript code makes an AJAX request to the server and processes the response. If the response indicates success, SweetAlert is used to display a success message; otherwise, an error message is shown.

Make sure to include the necessary CSS and JavaScript files for both Bootstrap and SweetAlert in your HTML file. Adjust the code according to your specific project structure and requirements.

Comment: The requirement was "procced to show sweet alert in loading mood until data is entered into database". This code doesn't do that

Comment: i seem to be missing something since this code is not doing anything. i am entering this ciode  `if ($successFlag) {
        $response = array('success' => true);
    } else {
        $response = array('success' => false);
    }
    
    echo json_encode($response);` inside my  insert data page and when i run it nothing happens even though i have added bootstrap and sweetalert and the described javascript to the form page. is their something i am missing ?? please help me